# How do I produce irregular cell merging in tables?

Tags: tables

How do I merge cells irregularly in tables?  I need to do this stuff for homework and don't feel like printing it out, writing it by hand, and scanning it back in to upload.

I could just hide the borders on the cells above the Answer column but then text wouldn't flow into that area.  I want a real non-rectangular cell.

[image: Irregular table cell]

Comment: I would recommend [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) for these kind of custom tables. It's on CTAN if you are looking for a manual.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot merge cells to make a non rectangular cells in tabular-like environments.  You can make a true non-rectagular areas of text (see shapepar manual and flowfram manual, subsection 3.1) but will be much simpler make "Work"  a single cell,  nest "Answer" as a table or framed minipage and deal with the problem of the text flow manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is a dirty trick  overlapping "Answers" and inserting an empty  `wrapfig` to make room in the "Work" text. Of course, you will need change the number of lines to overlap and find the right point to insert the empty wrapfig environment, according to your real contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum,wrapfig,parskip}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\extrarowheight2pt
\newcolumntype{A}{p{\dimexpr.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{B}{p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{C}{p{\dimexpr.75\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{D}{p{\dimexpr1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|A|A|A|A|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|B}{\centering Foo} & \multicolumn{2}{|B|}{\centering Bar}   \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|D|}{\bfseries Assumptions}\\
\multicolumn{4}{|D|}{\lipsum[2][1-3]}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|D|}{\bfseries Work}\\
\multicolumn{4}{|D|}{  
    \lipsum[2][1-4]
    \begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}[-\tabcolsep]{\dimexpr.25\linewidth} % <===
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[4][1-7] 
    \vspace{-4\baselineskip}}\\ % <===
\cline{4-4}
\multicolumn{3}{|C}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|A|}{\bfseries Answer}  \\
\multicolumn{3}{|C}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|A|}{\lipsum[1][1]}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 1):

I recommended [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) in comments but then I realised you want to have a cell as an inset. In this case I would recommend another package: [nicematrix](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix). One advantage is the ability to track locations of line intersections as well as cell positions. Then, you can insert figures via `tikz` in those locations.

The solution below still needs from you to workout two parameters:

- `hangafter`
- `hangindent`

and some knowledge about `tikz`.

Here's the code.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=4pt}
  \centering
  \caption{example}\label{tab:lab}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{X[c]|X[c]}[hvlines]
      Column 1 & Column 2 \\
      \Block{1-2}{\parbox{\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}{%
          \textbf{Assumptions}
          \par\kant[1][1]}} \\
      \Block{1-2}{\parbox{\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}{%
          \textbf{Work}
          \par\hangindent-\dimexpr0.25\linewidth+3\tabcolsep\hangafter3
          \kant[1][2-5]}}
    \CodeAfter\tikz
    \node[
      draw,
      line width = 1.2pt,
      inner sep = \tabcolsep,
      anchor=south east,
      yshift=-\arrayrulewidth,
    ] at (4-|3) {%
      \parbox{0.25\linewidth}{%
        \textbf{Answer}
        \par Human reason depends on our sense perceptions of something}};
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]